# Python websocket support on Azure web appservice?

Tags: python, azure, websocket, real-time, azure-web-app-service

Does Azure appservice has native websockets for Python like they do for [node.js/.net](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/)?

I'm assuming as of right now, the answer is no, and you'd need to use a VM to achieve this?

(fyi. there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425081/python-websocket-support-on-azure-web-apps?rq=1) but it's been deleted.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer if yes, Python websocket support on Azure Web Apps. The necessary steps or guideline as below.

1. First of all, you need to enable the `WEB SOCKETS` option of `Application settings` to `ON` on Azure portal, as the [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/) said as below, it's  matter with any languages.

[image]

2. Azure IIS supports Python webapp using WSGI, you can refer to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure#wsgi-handler) to know it and follow the tutorial content to build & configure your Python webapp with WSGI.
3. There is a similar [Combining websockets and WSGI in a python app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137449/combining-websockets-and-wsgi-in-a-python-app) SO thread which had been answered about the feasibility for websocket with WSGI in Python. And as references, there are some packages supported this combination, such as [Eventlet](http://eventlet.net/), [dwebsocket](https://github.com/duanhongyi/dwebsocket) for Django, etc that you can search the words `websocket` & `wsgi` to know more.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I have tried many samples, e.g.:

https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_wsgi
https://github.com/prashanthmadi/azure-appservice-py-websocket
but nothing so far has worked.

Answer (score 0):

When using Python, Azure App Service on Linux by default uses Gunicorn as webserver for all incoming requests. WebSocket connections start with a special HTTP GET request containing an "Upgrade" header which must be handled accordingly by the server. There are a few WSGI compatible WebSocket libraries out there, for this example I'm using [geventwebsocket](https://gitlab.com/noppo/gevent-websocket)

First, create a new Azure App Service Plan + Service:

```
az appservice plan create -g <ResourceGroupName> -n MyAppPlan --is-linux --number-of-workers 4 --sku S1
az webapp create -g <ResourceGroupName> -p MyAppPlan -n <AppServiceName> --runtime "PYTHON|3.7
```

Save the following sample to `server.py`:

```
from gevent import pywsgi
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

def websocket_app(environ, start_response):
    if environ["PATH_INFO"] == '/echo':
        ws = environ["wsgi.websocket"]
        while not ws.closed:
            message = ws.receive()
            ws.send(message)
```

Create a file `requirements.txt` with the following content

```
gevent
gevent-websocket
```

Create a file `.deployment` with the following content

```
[config]
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true
```

Put all three files in a zip folder `upload.zip` and deploy it to Azure

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip -g <ResourceGroupName> -n <AppServiceName> --src upload.zip
```

Set the startup command, we tell Gunicorn here to use a `GeventWebSocketWorker` for requests and serve the application in the file server.py, function name websocket_app.

```
az webapp config set -g <ResourceGroupName> -n <AppServiceName> --startup-file "gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 -k "geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker" server:websocket_app"
```

Enable WebSockets in Azure

```
az webapp config set -g <ResourceGroupName> -n <AppServiceName> --web-sockets-enabled true
```

After startup, you should now be able to send requests to the server and get an echo response (assuming the Python websockets package is installed - `pip install websockets`)

```
python -m websockets ws://<AppServiceName>.azurewebsites.net/echo
```